# Retrieving parameters from eclipse rcp/e4 in Handler

Tags: eclipse-rcp, e4

I have code to execute my handler/command, and it reaches here:

```java
@Execute
public Object execute(Shell shell) {
    System.out.println("Executing login!");
    return null;
}
```

However, I cannot find the injection service to provide me the parameters I passed in the command.

I tried:

```java
@Execute
public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event)
```

But it doesn't even see this method, and I suspect it's because that's not even an e4.* class.  I am aware of [Eclipse RCP 4 - Handler method parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17651022/eclipse-rcp-4-handler-method-parameters) but it doesn't tell me which service the command parameters are, e.g..:

```java
ParameterizedCommand myCommand = commandService.createCommand("mycommand.login", credentials);
Object result = handlerService.executeHandler(myCommand);
```

Where are my values from the credentials map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the whole `ParameterizedCommand` injected in the handler using:

```java
@Execute
public void execute(ParameterizedCommand command)
```

Or you can get the individual parameters using their ids:

```java
@Execute
public void execute(@Named("parameter id") String parameter)
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for.  But is this documented somewhere?

Comment: It is mentioned in Lars Vogella's [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseRCP/article.html) and his book (which is a longer version of the tutorial), both recommended.

Comment: Yes, I see that now, it is only on the one tutorial.